# Laravel global js ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, laravel

I try to collect some js functions global in the app.js. My app.js looks like this

```
// Import global dependencies
import './bootstrap';
import './argon';

export default class App {
    test() {
        console.log('test');
    }
}

jQuery(() => {
    window.App = new App();
});
```

In my blade view I try to call the test function on this way:

```
$(function () {
     App.test();
});
```

As result I get the error message `ReferenceError: App is not defined`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Since you are exporting the class, you cant reach it in the same page. One option is first define the App and then export it in another line, so that you can reach it.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: const App = class {/*your props*/};
export default App

Comment: @Markus In which app.js file have you put your code? If you have put it in `resources/js` you have to compile it.

Comment: Yes it's inside of the resource/js and i'ts successfully compiled with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to export an object you don't import anywhere. The jQuery code in your app.js is also unnecessary, there is no need to wait for the dom to be loaded before creating the `window.App` object.

```
import './bootstrap';
import './argon';

class App {
    test() {
        console.log('test');
    }
}

window.App = new App();
```